# Export version history from sharepoint online using webservices

Tags: sharepoint-online, versioning, version-history

I am using webservices to export web from sharepoint online.
Migration is working fine but versions are not getting migrated with the web. I am using ExportWeb method of /_vti_bin/Sites.asmx service. 
Is there any OOTB method to export versions along with other content ?

Comment: i always get a number 5 Status exception. I can't save the Export file in a doclib.
Can you help me with that problem?
If i can fix this, i think my next problem is the same as yours. Perhaps we can work together on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try SPServices' GetVersions function
http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Versions&referringTitle=%24%28%29.SPServices